# Should super always be at the top of an __init__ method, or can it be at the bottom?

Tags: python

In most Python examples, when super is used to call a parent class's constructors, it appears at the top.

Is it bad form to have it at the bottom of an **init** method?

In the examples below, super is at the bottom of A's constructor, but at the top of B's constructor.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do some stuff
        b = result_of_complex_operation()
        super(A, self).__init__(b)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__(b)
        # Do some stuff
```

Comment: If the class you're `super`ing requires the object to be in a certain state then you put it in that state before `super`... If your class requires the object to be in a certain state before it can continue its initialisation and that's provided by a parent class then you super that first. Hopefully someone will make a proper answer - but - it all depends...

Comment: as long as you actually _call_ the parent constructor...

Comment: Two very common cases: 1) you need to do pre-processing of the constructor's args, so that will require some code before `super()`; 2) do something about the instance variables defined by the superclass - that means you need code after ``super()``. So it really depends on the logic you're implementing

Comment: It really depends on how the constructor of the parent class works.

Answer (score 13):

This totally depends on the use case. Consider this.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.name)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

If you'd invoke `super()` before setting `self.name` within `Bar.__init__` you'd get an `AttributeError` because the required name has not yet been set.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it bad form to have it at the bottom of an init method?

You're asking the wrong question. Regardless of whether it's bad from or not, there are valid use cases for moving the superclass initialization to the bottom of a sub-class's constructor. Where to put the call to the superclass's constructor entirely depends on the implementation of the superclass's constructor.

For example, suppose you have a superclass. When constructing the superclass, you want to give an attribute a certain value depending on an attribute of the subclasses:

```
class Superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        if self.subclass_attr:
            self.attr = 1
        else:
            self.attr = 2
```

As you can see from above, we expect the subclasses to have the attribute `subclass_attr`. So what does this mean? *We can't initialize `Supperclass` until we've given the subclasses the `subclass_attr` attribute*.

Thus, we have to defer calling the superclass's constructor until we initialize `subclass_attr`. In other words, the call to `super` will have to be put at the bottom of a subclasses constructor:

```
class Subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.subclass_attr = True
        super(Superclass, self).__init__()
```

In the end, the choice of where to put `super` should not be based upon some style, but on what's necessary.

Comment: A correct and detailed answer. Just note that the example given illustrates a very poor design: ideally a superclass should never deal with attributes that exist only on its subclasses.

Comment: That's a fair point @MestreLion. Certainly not the best design, but my overall point in the answer was that the OP should be more concerned with how coding style can usually be contingent on what needs to get done.

Comment: Very inaccurate and dangerous code style. If super class should know 'subclass_attr' (what is ridiculous because of it is superclass attribute too) then `subclass_attr` should be renamed to more appropriate name and passed into superclass constructor as a separate parameter.

Comment: @DenisBarmenkov Just pretend that `subclass_attr` is an abstract method of Superclass` that `Subclass` implements, and you have a perfectly valid example where the parent doesn't know anything about the subclass. Besides, please refrain from calling other peoples work "ridiculous", this is not a place for ridiculing contributors.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen "subclass" prefix clearly means that it related to subclass not super class. "_attr" suffix means that it has to be an attribute. Duck typing in action.

Comment: @DenisBarmenkov To be clear. What is done in the example should be avoided, because the superclass knows about the implementation of the subclass. This is IMO a no-no, but we can make it "legal" by enforcing a contract with any implementing subclasses. One way of doing that is by making `subclass_attr` an abstract method of the superclass, that the subclass needs to implement. For good measure we can rename it to something more apt, like `pick_one()` or what have you. The name is pretty irrelevant, the goal of the example is to explain that, no, `super()` does not always go first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what happens in the parent class initialization.

## Early initialization of parent is required

In the following example the `Parent` class needs to be initialized for the `foo()` method to work, thus `super().__init__(foo_param)` must be called early if it is needed in the initialization of `Child`.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo_param: str):
        self._foo_param = foo_param

    def foo(self) -> FooResult:
        return do_something_with(self._foo_param)
        

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo_param: str):
        super().__init__(foo_param)  # Early init
        result = self.foo()  # Initial foo call
        # Use result for something
```

## Later initialization of parent is required

In the following example the `Parent` class requires that the `Child` class implements the abstract `foo()` method for it to be able to initialize, but the `Child` class needs to initialize a bit before it's implementation of the `foo()` method is ready. Thus `super().__init__()` can't come first.

```py
class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        result = self.foo()  # Initial foo call
        # Use result for something

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> FooResult:
        raise NotImplementedError()
        

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo_param: str):
        self._foo_param = foo_param  # Some prep is required for `foo()` to work
        super().__init__()  # Late init call

    def foo(self) -> FooResult:
        return do_something_with(self._foo_param)
```

Comment: It looks like the class constructor has to do some huge work rather than just initialize the instance. Perhaps this is done in order to write a one-liner in the code using the subclass.
Do you have a more specific real life example? Thank you.

Comment: No, `foo()` does not need to do huge work. It can be as basic as a constant, or have some simple logic that is needed to initialize the object before use, and maybe for later use. In any case. The answer is no, you cannot assume that `super()` can always be called first.